# Functions not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

This is the error I get while trying to create my first project in React.js, which is simply a sticky notes app. The whole warning displays this:

```html
printWarning    @   react-dom.development.js:61
error   @   react-dom.development.js:37
warnOnFunctionType  @   react-dom.development.js:13277
reconcileChildFibers    @   react-dom.development.js:14168
reconcileChildren   @   react-dom.development.js:17020
finishClassComponent    @   react-dom.development.js:17541
updateClassComponent    @   react-dom.development.js:17465
beginWork   @   react-dom.development.js:19103
beginWork$1 @   react-dom.development.js:23970
performUnitOfWork   @   react-dom.development.js:22809
workLoopSync    @   react-dom.development.js:22737
renderRootSync  @   react-dom.development.js:22700
performSyncWorkOnRoot   @   react-dom.development.js:22323
scheduleUpdateOnFiber   @   react-dom.development.js:21911
updateContainer @   react-dom.development.js:25512
(anonymous) @   react-dom.development.js:26051
unbatchedUpdates    @   react-dom.development.js:22461
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer    @   react-dom.development.js:26050
render  @   react-dom.development.js:26133
(anonymous) @   Inline Babel script:57
hq  @   babel.min.js:1
a   @   babel.min.js:1
yq  @   babel.min.js:1
(anonymous) @   babel.min.js:1
Cq  @   babel.min.js:1
kq  @   babel.min.js:1
```

Meanwhile, this is how my code looks like:

```css
.note {
        width: 250px;
        height: 150px;
        background-color: yellow;
        padding: 15px;
        border: 1px solid orange;
        box-shadow: 2px 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

class Note extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            editing: false
        }
    }


edit = () => { 
    this.setState = ({editing: true})
}

save = () => {
    var val = this.refs.newText.value
    alert( "The value will be stored as " + val)
    this.setState = ({editing: false})
}

delete() {
    alert( 'Deleting' )
}

renderForm = () => {
return (
    <div class="note">
        <textarea ref="newText"></textarea>
    <button onClick={this.save}>Save</button>
        </div>
)
}

renderDisplay = () => {
    return(  
        <div className="note"> 
            <p>{this.props.children}</p>
            <span>
                <button onClick={this.edit}>Edit</button>
                <button onClick={this.delete}>X</button>
                </span>
            </div>
    )
}

render() { 
    if(this.state.editing) {
        return this.renderForm
    } else {
        return this.renderDisplay
    }
}
}

ReactDOM.render(<Note>Hello World!</Note>, document.getElementById('react-container'))

    </script>
```

Can anyone help me to correct this? My page is blank and unable to display the note.

I should be able to see a yellow app which allows me to save notes.

Comment: `return this.renderForm()` with parentheses. You are just returning functions, not calling them.

Comment: thanks for your comment! I managed to see the app in chrome but when I press Edit it's still not opening the comment to add a new note.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with your render method, remember render should always return the component, you are just returning reference to the function ,so to over come you should make call to the function like

```
render() { 
  if(this.state.editing) {
    return this.renderForm()
  } else {
    return this.renderDisplay()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I fixed that error. However, despite I now can see the app in chrome, there's no reaction when I press the Edit button

Comment: check the code you have used to update state,the syntax is wrong

Comment: You mean this.setState = ({ editing: true })? That's an ES6 function, what's missing?